# I wrote a simple p nested pre in appsvelte but have an error

Tags: html, nested, element, svelte

I am working with App.svelte and in main I wrote the following code

```
<p>
<pre>
test
</pre>
</p>
```

but it results in an error

```
[plugin:vite-plugin-svelte] /src/App.svelte:209:0 &#60;/p> attempted to close &#60;p> that was already automatically closed by &#60;pre>
/src/App.svelte:209:0
207 |  
 208 | </pre>
 209 |  </p>
        ^
 210 |  
 211 |   <hr>
Click outside or fix the code to dismiss.
You can also disable this overlay by setting server.hmr.overlay to false in vite.config.js.
```

I expected `<p><pre>test</pre></p>` is a valid html code.

Comment: The nested code problem is  &#60;p>&#60;pre> test &#60;/pre>&#60;/p> that seems to valid for Svelte.

Comment: <main> <p><pre>test </pre></p></main> generate error in App.svelte